# Error: The argument type 'Future<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TimeOfDay'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add time picker to my flutter app.  I am trying to format the time in 12 hour clock time. But the problem is when i  try to pass my time variable to format it gives me error saying this.

> Error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TimeOfDay'.

This is how I have done this so far.

```
DateTime _currentDate = new DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay _currentTime = new TimeOfDay.now();



  Future <Null> selectedTime;

  String timeText = 'Set A Time';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    /// Time Picker

      MaterialLocalizations localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
      String formattedTime = localizations.formatTimeOfDay(selectedTime,  <--Here i am getting error
          alwaysUse24HourFormat: false);

      if (formattedTime != null) {
        setState(() {
          timeText = formattedTime;
        });
      }
```

> timepicker widget

TimePicker(

```
                  icon: Icons.access_time,
                  selectedTime: '$timeText',
                  onPress: () {


                    selectedTime = showTimePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialTime: _currentTime,
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectedTime` must be `TimeOfDay` not `Future<Null>`

Answer (score 0):

Change `selectedTime` to be of type `TimeOfDay`, change `onPress` to be an `async` function, and `await showTimePicker` so that you get the value of the `Future` instead of the `Future`:

```
TimeOfDay selectedTime;

TimePicker(
  icon: Icons.access_time,
  selectedTime: '$timeText',
  onPress: () async {
    selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _currentTime,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I am getting this error now `The getter 'hourOfPeriod' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: hourOfPeriod` what does this mean?

Comment: It means that somewhere in your code you are invoking `hourOfPeriod` on a variable that is null. You haven't shared that part of your code so I can't give any precise indications.